# Why is my OAuth not working with www in the url?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Is it intended? Do I need to redirect from www to non-www to get it working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OAuth 2.0 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-17#section-3.1.2) says:

> The redirection URI **MUST be an absolute URI** which
> MAY include a query component which MUST be retained by
> the authorization server when adding additional query parameters, and
> MUST NOT include a fragment component.

The grammer for absolute URI as defined by [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3) is :

```
absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]
```

It means each absolute-URI begins with a scheme name that refers to a specification for assigning identifiers within that scheme.

here is your answer:

Yes it is intended.
Redirection uri should be an Absolute-URI. it must starts with any scheme like http, https, ftp etc and followed by a colon(:).

eg: `http://www.google.com` is an absolute URI.

hope it would be helpful.